# Angular HttpClient Observable get array from nested hash with pipes() and map()

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4

I have some problems with RXJS Observables and pipes I don't understand.

My API returns a response like this

```
    {
      "_embedded": {
        "users": [
          {
             "id": 1,
             "username": "steve"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

And I have the following functions (very simplified for this question):

```
  listUsers() {
    return this.http.get<Users>(API_BASE_URL + '/v1/users').pipe(map(u => u._embedded.users))
  }

  getFirstUser() {
    return this.listUsers().pipe(first())
  }

  listUsersById() {
    return this.listUsers().pipe(reduce((acc, user) => { 
      acc[user.id] = user
      return acc
    }, {}))
  }
```

This is how I test it:

```
this.listUsers().subscribe(data => {
  console.log("FUNC: listUsers()")
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data[0])
})

this.listUsersById().subscribe(data => {
  console.log("FUNC: listUsersById()")
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data[0])
})

this.getFirstUser().subscribe(data => {
  console.log("FUNC: getFirstUser()")
  console.log(data)
})
```

listUsers() do what I expect it to, logs out an array of 11 user objects and then the first user object in the array.

listUsersById() logs out { undefined: [array of 11 user objects] }, should be a hash where the key is id and the value is the user object.

getFirstUser() logs out an array of 11 user objects (should be one)

The problem seems to be that rxjs don't treat the return value from listUsers() as an array "internally", making my pipe functions unusable.

**What I want is to create the "data pipeline" without resolving the function(s) until needed. How should I do this correctly when using the Angular HTTPClient that returns a promise?**

If I resolve the http request and have the data available in an array it works without problems.:

```
from([
      {
        id: 1,
        username: "steve"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        username: "jane"
      }
    ]).pipe(reduce((acc, user) => {
      acc[user.id] = user
      return acc
    }, {}))
```

Comment: Your listUsers() method returns an Observable <Array<User>>. It emits one and only one event, which is an array of users (Array<User>). Your from() call at the end does something completely different. It creates an Observable<User>. This observable emits two events, and each of them is a User. You can see it as the difference between an email containing two attached files, and two emails, each containing a single attached file.

Comment: Your getFirstUser(), for example, makes no sense: using the `first` operator on an observable that emits only once won't do anything useful. If you want to transform an Observable<Array<User>> into an Observable<User>, then the correct operator is map(array -> array[0]).

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer! Makes total sense now, when you explained it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jb-nizet explained in his comments, the event only emits once.

Based on that, one simple implementation to solve listUsersById() would be this:

```
  listUsersById() {
    return this.listUsers().pipe(map(u => u.reduce((acc, user) => { 
      acc[user.id] = user
      return acc
    }, {})))
  }
```

Another option is to use flatMap() to emit one event for each item in the array like this:

```
  listUsers() {
    return this.http.get<Users>(API_BASE_URL + '/v1/users').pipe(map(u => u._embedded.users), flatMap(x => x))
  }
```

This way the original implementation of getUsersById() works as wanted, but in my case it makes no or little sense to do it this way.